# asp.net MVC 5 identity 2 adding columns to AspNetRoles table

Tags: asp.net-identity

Can I add more columns into AspNetRoles table ? (Kinda database first approach)
Will the framework pick new column automatically or do I have to change any auto-generated code ?
When I added columns to AspNetUsers I had to modify class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser but I don't see any class generated for Roles.

What I'd like to do is have additional info where the role is used (eg. Area) so then I can group it in my view and maybe also detailed description of each role...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer to my own question at [codeplex](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/727054/ASP-NET-MVC-Identity-Extending-and-Modifying-R)

Comment: It's applicable to ASP.NET Identity v1, not version 2